# Calculation of RMSE for random forest model

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest

I'm building a random forest regression model in R to forecast sales demand and comparing it to other traditional forecasting models, such as naive, mean, holts method, exponential smoothing, etc. The performance metric used to compare the models is RMSE. For the traditional models, its quite straightforward to calculate the RMSE: Just take the difference between the actual observations and prediction, square these residuals, take the mean, and then take the square root.

For the random forest model, it seems that the RMSE isn't calculated directly from the resample predictions vs. actual observations, but rather takes the mean of the RMSE of all the resamples:

```
Random Forest 

93 samples
10 predictors

No pre-processing
Resampling: Rolling Forecasting Origin Resampling (1 held-out with no fixed window) 
Summary of sample sizes: 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, ... 
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  splitrule   RMSE      Rsquared  MAE     
  variance    9.566489  NaN       9.566489
  extratrees  9.654556  NaN       9.654556

Tuning parameter 'mtry' was held constant at a value of 3
RMSE was used to select the optimal model using  the smallest value.
The final values used for the model were mtry = 3 and splitrule = variance.
```

The 9.566489 can also be calculated by taking the mean of the resample RMSEs:

```
mean(randomforest[["resample"]][["RMSE"]])
[1] 9.566489
```

Whenever I calculate the RMSE based on the actual observations vs. the resample predictions, I get a different RMSE:

```
rmse(randomforest$pred$pred, randomforest$pred$obs)
[1] 13.54068
```

Why is the RMSE automatically calculated using the average of the resample RMSE instead of like the other models (rmse of predictions compared to actual observations)? Which RMSE is considered the final RMSE of the random forest model. I need to have a consistent calculation among all models in order to make a fair comparison.